# Using CDNJS with LibMan for Moment.JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to get into ***Asp.Net Core 2.2 MVC*** right now.
I want to use the ***moment.js*** library for some date calculations due to values from a DevExpress datetime picker. I have been able to include it according to the following [instructions](https://www.maherjendoubi.io/using-cdnjs-with-libman-for-aspnetcore/) using "libman.json":

```
{
  "provider": "cdnjs",
  "library": "moment.js@2.23.0",
  "destination": "wwwroot/lib/moment.js/",
  "files": [
    "moment-with-locales.min.js",
    "locale/de.js"
  ]
}
```

The *.js files are available.

[image: a busy cat]

However, the type or the factory 'moment()' cannot be used as described on the page https://momentjs.com/docs/ (there's no special sample for MVC either). It does not exist.
I have also tried to use the nuget 'Moment.js', but it is also not possible to reference it.

I tried something like this in my *.cshtml ... but that's more Angular rather than MVC, isn't it?

@section Scripts {

```
<script>
    import $ from jquery;
    import moment from moment;
    const m = moment();

    function dateDiff(secondDate) {            
        //var a = moment([2008, 9]);
        //var b = moment([2007, 0]);
        //a.diff(b, 'years');
        return $("#age").text("" + " years");
    }
</script>
```

}

I'm not able to get access to the moment.js type.
What do I have to do? What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance! Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using `moment`, you need to reference it.

For short using, you could try like below:

```
@section Scripts{ 
    <script src="~/lib/moment.js/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var now = moment();
            alert(now);
            var a = moment([2008, 9]);
            var b = moment([2007, 0]);
            alert(a.diff(b, 'years'));
        });
    </script>
}
```

You also could register `moment` in global by `_Layout.cshtml`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    //rest code
    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha256-E/V4cWE4qvAeO5MOhjtGtqDzPndRO1LBk8lJ/PR7CA4=">
        </script>
    </environment>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/moment.js/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tao Zhou - thank you very much for your answer.
Of course I tried to reference/register it in my _layout.cshtml.

The problem was somewhere else... I have tested CodeRush from DevExpress as an IntelliSense......
For JavaScript this IntelliSense does not seem to recognize the type for moment.js, and maybe any type of js.
So I thought the reference would not work, but in fact it was just a problem with the IDE extension!

So ReSharper... here we are again :)